# Consumption of API Requests on DEV org

Tags: api, force.com, ide

I was reviewing the System Overview page in my Dev org when I noticed that the 'API REQUESTS, LAST 24 HOURS' was seemingly very high for a single user Dev org (initially at 2,964 or 58%).

I did a quick calculation based on the number of hours I've been working and realised that this was ridiculous given the amount of times I deploy or run tests.

So, as a further test I 'Save[d] to Server' an Apex class and noted that the requests jumped from 2,964 to 2,988.

Is this normal and I have simply never noticed before, or is something likely amiss?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Metadata API has never really been the most optimal API for an IDE, hence Salesforce are now working on the Tooling API (currently in Pilot). So I would not be surprised to see it use more than one, but 24 API requests does seem quite excessive. I have just done a Save and consumed 3 API requests. There is a report you can run to get a little more information.

Click on Reports, and under the Administrative Reports folder you'll find this...

[image]

[Force.com API Usage Limits](https://na11.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/integrate_api_rate_limiting.htm#rate_limits_title)

Comment: +1 for the useful info, pretty sure it's org related - tried on another dev org and it only consumed 9 requests. Thanks for your help.